# In python, i dont know why but in my code im appending to a list but when i check the list theres nothing inside

Tags: python, list, append

I'm learning python and im still a beginner and heres my problem:

```
toppinglist = []
instock = ['Cheese', 'Tomato', 'Chicken', 'Mushroom']
Outofstock = ['Beef', 'Pork', 'Onions']
wanttoppings_q = input('Do you want toppings on your pizza? Yes/No')
wanttoppings_q = wanttoppings_q.title()
while wanttoppings_q == 'Yes':
    requestedtopping = input('Enter One Topping:')
    toppinglist.append(requestedtopping)
    anythingelse = input('Anything Else? Yes/No' )
    anythingelse = anythingelse.title()
    toppinglist = []
    if anythingelse == 'No':
        break

print(toppinglist)
```

with this block of code, basically goal is asking what pizza toppings you want then adding that to a list, i tried using my brain and came up with this. Everything is fine, while loop fine but then i print the topping list and nothings inside. Maybe im using append wrong? pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are  resetting the toppinglist = [] before you are printing it so remove that everything will work fine

```
toppinglist = []
instock = ['Cheese', 'Tomato', 'Chicken', 'Mushroom']
Outofstock = ['Beef', 'Pork', 'Onions']
wanttoppings_q = input('Do you want toppings on your pizza? Yes/No ')
wanttoppings_q = wanttoppings_q.title()
while wanttoppings_q == 'Yes':
    requestedtopping = input('Enter One Topping: ')
    toppinglist.append(requestedtopping)
    anythingelse = input('Anything Else? Yes/No ')
    anythingelse = anythingelse.title()
    if anythingelse == 'No':
        break

print(toppinglist)
```

Comment: THAT FIXED IT, THANKS I FEEL DUMB NOW LOL